# web api Newtonsoft converter with access to Net.Http.HttpContent

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am new to web api so apologies if my question sounds stupid.

I am trying to implement a custom converter to deserialize date fields. My form renders date fields as 2 text boxes (date and time) so when the form is submitted, in my custom converter i wanted to concatenate both values and return a datetime object.

As far as i can see, there is no way of accessing the request from my ReadJson function in the converter. Is there a way of accessing the request when deserializing a primitive type property?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to Global.asax.cs and format your date and time in the ReadJson overridden method.

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new YouDateTimeConverter());
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have already setup my custom converter and i can see the ReadJson function being called. What i am struggling with is accessing the request from this function.